# Install Deamon (Zookeeper) but don't automatically start it

Tags: apt, 18.04, systemd

I've installed zookeeper and zookeeperd on 18.04 directly from the APT sources.
That works fine, but it gets started automatically. How can I prevent this?

Stopping the daemon afterward is possible, but i has a change that it will create any data with the example config.

We need this for immutable VM images, so i don't want to have any artifacts in the image.

I am sure this is not Zookeeper specific but I was not able to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
sudo systemctl disable zoo
```

If you’d like to prevent daemons from starting after installing a package, just toss a few lines into `/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d`:

```
sudo -i
cat > /usr/sbin/policy-rc.d << EOF
#!/bin/sh
echo "All runlevel operations denied by policy" >&2
exit 101
EOF
exit
```

Now, install any packages that you need and the daemons will remain stopped until you start them (or reboot the server). Be sure to remove the policy file you added once you’re done installing your packages.

Comment: Yes but, at this time the Service has already started and their is maye some data written, from the wrong example config.

Comment: You wont to install zookeeper and not start it directly after installing?

Comment: Yes, we use Immutable images on VM basis and try to create the image first.

Comment: @MarkEisenblätter i've edited main reply :) please check if it works for you, if yes please upvote my comment :D